# AttributeError: object has no attribute?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Alrighty so this is the error I get:
AttributeError: 'DES' object has no attribute 'summary_output'

So this is what I am trying to do.

When I am on this frame, I am creating a text variable that is then sent to a set class.

```
class upload_csv(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master, width=250, height=160, bg='white')
        
        self.upload_csv_btn = Button(
                self.frame,
                text="Add Data Source",
                fg="DodgerBlue4",
                font=("Graph Type", 15),
                height=1, width=20,
                borderwidth=2,
                relief="groove",
                command=self.upload)

        self.upload_csv_btn.place(x=10, y=10)
        
        self.frame.pack()
        
    def upload(self):
        global text
        self.xvalues = []
        self.yvalues = []
        self.xyvalues = []
        self.header = []
       
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        if len(filename) != 0:
            print('Selected:', filename)
            with open(filename) as file:
                csvreader = csv.reader(file)
                self.header.append(next(csvreader)) 
                for row in csvreader:
                    if len(row) == 3:
                        self.xvalues.append(int(row[0]))
                        self.yvalues.append(int(row[1]))
                        self.xyvalues.append(int(row[2])) 
                        text = (
                            self.header[0][0]+ ": " + str(self.xvalues).replace('[','').replace(']','') + 
                            "\n\n" + self.header[0][1] + ": " + str(self.yvalues).replace('[','').replace(']','') + 
                            "\n\n" + self.header[0][2] + ": " + str(self.xyvalues).replace('[','').replace(']',''))   
                        
                    elif len(row) == 2:
                        self.xvalues.append(row[0])
                        self.yvalues.append(row[1])  
                        text = (
                            self.header[0][0] + ": " + str(self.xvalues).replace('[','').replace(']','') + 
                            "\n\n" + self.header[0][1] + ": " + str(self.yvalues).replace('[','').replace(']',''))
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
        s = Set(text)                        
        s.set_summary()
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Using the upload class, I am sending the variable by calling the set class, and calling the set_summary method. With this set class, I am setting the string as a an object item, that is then send to my DES class. I want this item to be set on a tk textbox element as a summary. I receive the text fine in the DES class, but I get the following error when trying to modify the summary element.
The error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\***\Documents\Workspace\***\***\view\upload_csv.py", line 115, in upload
    s.set_summary()
  File "C:\Users\***\Documents\Workspace\***\***\view\Set.py", line 14, in set_summary
    s.set_summary_text()
  File "C:\Users\***\Documents\Workspace\***\***\view\test.py", line 164, in set_summary_text
    print(self.summary_output)
AttributeError: 'DES' object has no attribute 'summary_output'
```

My set class:

```
class Set:
    def __init__ (self, summary):
        self.summary = summary
        
    def set_summary(self):
        print(self.summary)
        s = DES(self.summary)                        
        s.set_summary_text()
```

My DES Class:

```
class DES(Frame):
    def __init__(self, summary):
        self.summary = summary
        
    def createFrame(self, master):
        self.frame = tk.Frame(master, width=750, height=968,bg='white')
        self.summary_output = tk.Text(
                        self.frame, 
                        height=8,
                        width=78,
                        bg="gray95",
                        borderwidth=2, 
                        relief="groove",
                        font=("Arial", 12))

        self.summary_output.configure(state='disabled') 

      
        self.summary_output.place(x=20, y=610)
        
        self.frame.pack()
       

    def set_summary_text(self):
        print(self.summary)
        print(self.summary_output)
        self.summary_output.configure(state='normal')
        self.summary_output.delete('1.0', END) # Remote all text
        self.summary_output.insert('end',self.summary)
        self.summary_output.configure(state='disabled')  #Make text widget read only 

def main(): 
    global root
    root = tk.Tk()
    # app = DES(root)
    # app = DES.createFrame(root)
    s = DES("")                        
    s.createFrame(root)
    root.mainloop()
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Edit:

So after trying the answer I got the following error, all I did was add the suggestion:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\***\Documents\Workspace\\***\\***\view\upload_csv.py", line 115, in upload
    s.set_summary()
  File "C:\Users\\***\Documents\Workspace\\***\view\Set.py", line 22, in set_summary
    s.createFrame(root)
  File "C:\Users\\***\Documents\Workspace\\***\view\test.py", line 120, in createFrame
    self.canvas.draw() # Create the graph canvas
  File "C:\Users\\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 11, in draw
    self._master.update_idletasks()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'update_idletasks'
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 235, in filter_destroy
    self._master.update_idletasks()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'update_idletasks'
```

So I remove the matplot graph and got this error:
[image]

So maybe the graph is interfering? Im not sure, I need the graph.

Comment: I do not get an error when running your code

Comment: also you shuld not use the keyword set, its a reseved word in python

Comment: Hi Travis, please check my answer out.

Comment: @BendikKnapstad Check again I see errors

Comment: @BehdadAbdollahiMoghadam please see edit as I noticed errors

Answer (score 3):

- The `summary_output` in `DES` class, will be defined in the
  `createFrame` method.
- You first instatiated from the `DES` class in the `Set.set_summary()`
  method and then called the `set_summary_text()` method, which it uses
  the `summary_output`. That's not correct, since the `summary_output` has not been defined, yet.
- You should first, call the `createFrame()` method to define the
  `summary_output` attribute and then call the `set_summary_text()` to
  use summary_output.

Do something like this, in the `Set` class:

```py
class Set:
    def __init__ (self, summary):
        self.summary = summary
        
    def set_summary(self):
        global root
        print(self.summary)
        s = DES(self.summary)   
        s.createFrame(root)                     
        s.set_summary_text()
```

Or do whatever you think it's best for you, but you should define the `summary_output` first, and then `print` or use it.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the reply. I gave it a try and got the following error:

Comment: Please see edit

Comment: So my answer, removed your error.. and you have a new error?
If you please don't change the question, and put another question for the new bug and error.

Comment: No, your answer created a new error

Comment: I added as an edit, of the errors that came up from your 'fix'

Comment: I think your code has some more bugs, and removing one bug, will reveal more bugs.. it's a normal thing in programming

Comment: thats why im asking for help

Comment: I don't know, how you want your code to be ... but I just mentioned that, the previous error was from not defining the `summary_output` before using it, and the code I posted was a hint, and not the exact way to handle the error.

Comment: dont be rude, Travis B, this guy has taken the time to help you with an error you made. His "fix" as you call  it is a fix, your code just has more bugs in it. Thats entirely your doing, not his. He helped you remove a bug.